# Vowel detection in WebAudio

Tags: web-audio-api, frequency-analysis

Any advice on how to acheive vowel detection using WebAudio?

I assume somthing with `analyser.getFloatFrequencyData`

Hoping someone may have some insight.

Comment: Find an algorithm you want to use for vowel detection and come back here if you can't figure out how to implement it using WebAudio.  You will probably want to use either a `ScriptProcessorNode` or `AudioWorkletNode` to implement it.

Comment: Reliably detecting vowel from non-vowel from silence from unrestricted background noise is not at all simple.  It only seems simple because of how easy it is for your own ears to do it.  I don't intend to be mean or nasty, here, only matter-of-fact:  The fact that you're thinking "something with analyser.getFloatFrequencyData" implies that you don't have a good grasp of the scope of your project, and that even if you are good at audio processing, you need to do some background reading in the signal processing of phonetics.  A good key phrase is "Vowel formant space."

Comment: For what it’s worth, I never said this would be a simple task... just trying to get a conversation started on this topic. I appreciate the feedback.